# Cannot uninstall ClamAV from Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, uninstall, clamav

I've been trying to use Ubuntu after being a long-time Windows user. So a few months back, one of the first things I've tried was installing the antivirus ClamAV. However, not being used to using commands, I think I may have messed a bunch of things up. I didn't think much of it but recently I've decided I should probably start looking into ClamAV properly. I figured I should remove and reinstall it.

I checked where ClamAV and freshclam are located:

```
$ whereis clamav
clamav: /etc/clamav
$ whereis freshclam
freshclam: /usr/local/bin/freshclam /usr/local/etc/freshclam.conf
```

Since the packages were found, I thought I could remove them with `sudo apt-get remove` but to no avail:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove freshclam
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package freshclam
$ sudo apt-get remove clamav
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'clamav' is not installed, so not removed
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 16 not to upgrade.
```

The ClamAV [uninstall page](https://www.clamav.net/documents/uninstalling-clamav) isn't very helpful, so I was wondering what I could do to do a full uninstall.

If possible, I would also appreciate a clearer guide on how to use ClamAV because I find the [official documentation](https://www.clamav.net/documents/usage) rather confusing.

Comment: How did you INSTALL it. It probably was not using `apt`.

Comment: I think I might have installed it from source but I don't remember anymore, sorry :/

Comment: Well that would make sense: you need to use the opposite of what you used to install to uninstall ;-)